# Visual Studio 2017, Cannot find name 'Office' when compiling typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, office-js

I am converting a VSTO Add-in for Word to the new Office Add-in format. I have installed the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 Community. I am attempting to use typescript in my code, but I can not get any reference to Office.js to compile.  It comes back with the error "TS2304 TypeScript (TS) Cannot find name 'Office'."

As a test I have created a brand new WordWebAddin from the templates provided.  I then created a new typescript file under the Functions folder named file1.ts. The file contains the following code:

```
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {

    };
})();
```

I suspect I am missing something simple. I have searched extensively but cannot seem to find the solution I need, as a lot of the search results are for Visual Studio 2015 and a bunch has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JAllen, apologies for the delayed response. We've updated the docs to provide guidance for using Visual Studio 2017: [Convert an Office Add-in project in Visual Studio to TypeScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript). Please give that a try, and feel free to comment here if the updated guidance doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: Happy to hear you're unblocked now; thanks for bringing this issue to our attention!

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing the reference to Office-js library in the HTML. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn) for instructions. If you are using Visual Studio tool, you can use the starter project to get started. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-get-started-jquery?tabs=visual-studio) for a sample (though the example is is for Excel, the process is the same for Word)

Comment: The Add-in was generated using the Visual Studio New - Project wizard.  The Home.html page has  `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`   in the <Head> element.

Comment: Also, the same exact code compiles fine in the FunctionFile.js as well as Home.js.  It just will not compile in any TypeScript file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using VS to begin with. We don't have a VS 2017 based instructions for TypeScript... we're working on it. You can reference 2015 instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript) for TypeScript. If that doesn't work, I encourage you to look at Yo Office tool that does create TypeScript template add-in.

Comment: I have been through the 2015 tutorial a bunch of times.  Unfortunately, very little of it seems to apply.  For instance, when you change Home.js to Home.ts nothing happens.  There is no prompt for Nuget Package Manager.  Plus my understanding is that TypeScript is already installed in 2017 so that step is not necessary?

Comment: Just to clarify, It is compiling typescript fine, as long as there is no reference to Office.js

Comment: Understood. We'll get back with instructions for VS2017 as soon as possible.

Comment: @JAllen, as a stop-gap solution, the simplest thing might be to create an empty "Office.d.ts" file somewhere in your project and then copy-paste the contents from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/office-js/index.d.ts" into it.  It should "just work".

Comment: Alternatively, if you know how to use `npm` tooling, you should be able to do `npm install @types/office-js --savedev` and save yourself the copy-pasting (and make it easier to keep it updated)

Comment: Hi Michael.  I installed the @types/office using NPM like you said.  The project will now compile but it is treating the Office type as "any", and still not finding it as a valid type.  I took a screenshot of the project. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N41hI.png)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft, could you possibly help me out with this followup question regarding polyfilling promises? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229971/how-to-polyfill-promise-in-visual-studio-2017-office-add-in

Comment: On an angular 5 project, even installing @types/office-js wouldn't work. I still get the cannot find name error :O. Note that, I have a bit of experiment and in my IDE (WebStorm), the type are recognize and all definitions are there :O